# Get Video Data in Videos Application

Tags: swift, video, mpmediaitem, mpmedialibrary

I want my player to play videos that are in `Video` app.

I access `Media Library`, and want to get list of videos, and when user selected a video, my player get the video data and play it on my own player.

How can I get the video data?

Notice that I want to play videos, not songs.

This is my code to get videos:

```
let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: MPMediaType.anyVideo.rawValue, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType)
    let query = MPMediaQuery()
    query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)
    let items = query.items!
```

It takes videos as `MPMediaItem`.

Does it takes videos correctly? If yes, I want to get a video data after user selected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Scriptable is right. But notice that downloaded videos will not be accessible through `Videos` (renamed to `TV`) application! `TV` shows iTunes purchased movies.

You can access downloaded videos through `Photos` (Gallery). If you mean downloaded videos from the web or other apps.

Comment: Sorry. You are right, I thought videos will be saved in Videos.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, at least by using [MediaPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer).

You can only access videos stored in the Photos app/library.

> Use the Media Player framework—which is part of **MusicKit**—to control playback of the user's media from your app. If your app incorporates music, **you can use this framework to search for audio content** (songs, podcasts, books, and so on) in the user's library. You can then play that content directly or ask the system Music app to play it. For example, a game might give users the option to play their own music while completing a particular game level. **(Emphasis mine)**

Comment: I want to access downloaded Videos. How can I do this?

Comment: "I don't think it is possible"

Comment: I've seen Apps that do this, like "PlayerXtreme". In the app, select IPHONE tab, and then select Videos folder. Downloaded videos will be shown.

Comment: These are shown from the camera roll and not the videos app I believe, the videos app is sandboxed and its documents are not accesible